# How to return a response while method is still running

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku

I have uploaded a Django App on Heroku (Free Tier) where the user can upload some .xlsx files and generate a final spreadsheet based on them.

The main page consists of three buttons, `Upload, Generate, Download` and everything works perfectly when it has to do with small files. But When I upload bigger files the `Generate` process takes a lot longer which leads to `error: H12` in Heroku.

I tried working with rq as suggested by Heroku, but with no success. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my views.py file

```
def main(request):
    q = Queue(connection=Redis())

    if request.method == "POST" and 'cta-button-generate' in request.POST:
        q.enqueue(webControl.generate_files())
        return render(request, template_name='main.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time consuming processes, must be ran on background. I used Celery to do it